# Can I use inheritance on Declarative/Scripted Jenkins pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I'll create one project which will have some methods like:

- retrive codes from SCM,
- install npm packages
- build project (angular)
- run tests of the project (today in karma framework but later it'll change)
- create package (npm)
- publish the package (currently to private npm server but later it might be npmjs or some other servers)

this steps will work for more than 20 different projects and I don't want to update every project just because I changes npm server or way of testing. I need to inherit these projects from one which has methods can be overwritable.

Do you know this can be handled by Jenkins Scripted/Declarative pipelines and if the answer yes, would you please share any resource/example etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Shared Libraries](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/). There's couple of methods to make your pipeline code reusable.

Although, for global changes of simple values (like server address) the simplest solution would be setting global environment (*Manage Jenkins -> Global Properties -> Environment variables*).